# How to get through the Youtube API the number of "Concurrent Views" of a Live transmission

Tags: api, youtube

I was able to get the total number of views through `part = statistics` at `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/list`, but I can get the number of "Concurrent Views". of views differs from what appears on the Youtube Live Stream Dashboard. Can someone help me? I didn't find any updated questions about this in 2022. It seems to me that Youtube doesn't offer this in the API anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I managed to understand, in `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[CHANNELID]&eventType=live&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]` After getting the VideoID, I make a new request in `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id=[VIDEOID]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`. Thus, I get the amount of live viewers.